# How to convert a dict which is inside a list inside an array of json object into a dataframe?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have an array in json text file which has a list of dicts. I need to extract all of it into a dataframe. Array is something on these lines:-

```
[{ "_id" : "abc" , "players" : [ "1" , "2"] , "tId" : "1" , "ef" : 200 , "pr" : 360 , "mode" : 1.0 , "1" : { "before" : { "rm" : { "$numberLong" : "1070"} , "cap" : 450.0 , "nrrm" : 20.0} , "after" : { "rm" : { "$numberLong" : "970"} , "cap" : 250.0 , "nrrm" : 120.0}} , "2" : { "before" : { "rm" : { "$numberLong" : "470"} , "cap" : 0.0 , "nrrm" : 310.0} , "after" : { "rm" : { "$numberLong" : "730"} , "cap" : 0.0 , "nrrm" : 410.0}} , "ts" : { "$date" : { "$numberLong" : "1565548200670"}} , "shots" : [ { "iBS" : 1 , "bSTOP" : 1 , "aSTOP" : 1 , "bSPB" : "NOT DECIDED" , "aSPB" : "NOT DECIDED" , "lBP" : [ 1] , "iBP" : [ ] , "bP" : [ 1] , "iTO" : 0 , "iCOPG" : 0 , "nTCCOP" : 0 , "iCOPS" : 0 , "cBP" : "( -0.6728522,0.04,-0.5520813 )" , "iF" : "( 0.480835,-2.9104E-16,0.1699932 )" , "iP" : "( -0.7105647,0.04,-0.5654141 )" , "cA" : "( 6.539359E-14,70.5296,2.670466E-14 )" , "iTBA" : 1 , "tBID" : 2 , "tBP" : "( 0.724014,0.0335,-0.041 )" , "tT" : 12.66367 , "iSU" : "" , "uSV" : "" , "iPB" : 0 , "bHBC" : 7 , "cHRB" : 1 , "cHSM" : 1 , "hRBIP" : 1 , "cIH" : 0 , "cIP" : 0 , "bIP" : 0 , "aBP" : 1 , "iGO" : 0 , "sSC" : 0 , "sBC" : 0 , "dBC" : 0 , "cSC" : 0 , "iSC" : 0 , "pSId" : "2cfdd0" , "toT" : 12.63438} , { "iBS" : 0 , "bSTOP" : 1 , "aSTOP" : 0 , "bSPB" : "NOT DECIDED" , "aSPB" : "SOLID BALLS" , "lBP" : [ 3] , "iBP" : [ ] , "bP" : [ 3] , "iTO" : 0 , "iCOPG" : 0 , "nTCCOP" : 0 , "iCOPS" : 0 , "cBP" : "( 1.07788,0.04,-0.5111128 )" , "iF" : "( -0.2340834,1.694598E-16,0.4531059 )" , "iP" : "( 1.096239,0.04,-0.5466505 )" , "cA" : "( -3.80758E-14,332.6783,-1.613636E-14 )" , "iTBA" : 1 , "tBID" : 3 , "tBP" : "( 0.4538818,0.04000001,0.54636 )" , "tT" : 15.64122 , "iSU" : "" , "uSV" : "( 0,0,0 )" , "iPB" : 0 , "bHBC" : 4 , "cHRB" : 1 , "cHSM" : 1 , "hRBIP" : 1 , "cIH" : 0 , "cIP" : 0 , "bIP" : 0 , "aBP" : 1 , "iGO" : 0 , "sSC" : 0 , "sBC" : 0 , "dBC" : 0 , "cSC" : 0 , "iSC" : 0 , "pSId" : "2cfdd0" , "toT" : 15.62162} , { "iBS" : 0 , "bSTOP" : 0 , "aSTOP" : 0 , "bSPB" : "SOLID BALLS" , "aSPB" : "SOLID BALLS" , "lBP" : [ ] , "iBP" : [ ] , "bP" : [ ] , "iTO" : 0 , "iCOPG" : 0 , "nTCCOP" : 0 , "iCOPS" : 0 , "cBP" : "( 0.1115417,0.04,-0.1958274 )" , "iF" : "( 0.002243765,-1.426218E-18,0.0006675497 )" , "iP" : "( 0.07320246,0.04,-0.2072338 )" , "cA" : "( 6.981425E-14,73.43156,3.15853E-14 )" , "iTBA" : 1 , "tBID" : 5 , "tBP" : "( 0.7939866,0.04000001,-0.07077976 )" , "tT" : 24.50556 , "iSU" : "" , "uSV" : "( 0,0,0 )" , "iPB" : 0 , "bHBC" : 0 , "cHRB" : 0 , "cHSM" : 0 , "hRBIP" : 0 , "cIH" : 1 , "cIP" : 0 , "bIP" : 0 , "aBP" : 0 , "iGO" : 0 , "sSC" : 0 , "sBC" : 0 , "dBC" : 0 , "cSC" : 0 , "iSC" : 0 , "pSId" : "2cfdd0" , "toT" : 24.4843} , { "iBS" : 0 , "bSTOP" : 0 , "aSTOP" : 0 , "bSPB" : "STRIPE BALLS" , "aSPB" : "STRIPE BALLS" , "lBP" : [ 14] , "iBP" : [ ] , "bP" : [ 14] , "iTO" : 0 , "iCOPG" : 0 , "nTCCOP" : 0 , "iCOPS" : 0 , "cBP" : "( -0.1471594,0.04,0.2157262 )" , "iF" : "( 0.09524104,0,0.1471072 )" , "iP" : "( -0.1688982,0.04,0.182149 )" , "cA" : "( 0,32.92009,0 )" , "iTBA" : 1 , "tBID" : 14 , "tBP" : "( -0.06695016,0.04000001,0.3848823 )" , "tT" : 9.197196 , "iSU" : "" , "uSV" : "( 0,0,0 )" , "iPB" : 0 , "bHBC" : 0 , "cHRB" : 1 , "cHSM" : 1 , "hRBIP" : 1 , "cIH" : 0 , "cIP" : 0 , "bIP" : 0 , "aBP" : 1 , "iGO" : 0 , "sSC" : 1 , "sBC" : 0 , "dBC" : 0 , "cSC" : 0 , "iSC" : 0 , "pSId" : "1bdf72" , "toT" : 9.181252} , { "iBS" : 0 , "bSTOP" : 0 , "aSTOP" : 0 , "bSPB" : "STRIPE BALLS" , "aSPB" : "STRIPE BALLS" , "lBP" : [ 12] , "iBP" : [ ] , "bP" : [ 12] , "iTO" : 0 , "iCOPG" : 0 , "nTCCOP" : 0 , "iCOPS" : 0 , "cBP" : "( 0.3852863,0.04,0.4167935 )" , "iF" : "( 0.282476,0,0.2797301 )" , "iP" : "( 0.3568642,0.04,0.3886477 )" , "cA" : "( 0,45.27985,0 )" , "iTBA" : 1 , "tBID" : 12 , "tBP" : "( 0.6180266,0.04000001,0.5658391 )" , "tT" : 6.139053 , "iSU" : "" , "uSV" : "( 0,0,0 )" , "iPB" : 0 , "bHBC" : 7 , "cHRB" : 1 , "cHSM" : 1 , "hRBIP" : 1 , "cIH" : 0 , "cIP" : 0 , "bIP" : 0 , "aBP" : 1 , "iGO" : 0 , "sSC" : 0 , "sBC" : 0 , "dBC" : 0 , "cSC" : 0 , "iSC" : 0 , "pSId" : "1bdf72" , "toT" : 6.123772} , { "iBS" : 0 , "bSTOP" : 0 , "aSTOP" : 0 , "bSPB" : "STRIPE BALLS" , "aSPB" : "STRIPE BALLS" , "lBP" : [ 11] , "iBP" : [ ] , "bP" : [ 11] , "iTO" : 0 , "iCOPG" : 0 , "nTCCOP" : 0 , "iCOPS" : 0 , "cBP" : "( 0.7701012,0.04,-0.2259813 )" , "iF" : "( 0.200658,0,-0.4688671 )" , "iP" : "( 0.7543634,0.04,-0.1892074 )" , "cA" : "( 0,156.8309,0 )" , "iTBA" : 1 , "tBID" : 11 , "tBP" : "( 0.941402,0.04000002,-0.4693463 )" , "tT" : 5.77317 , "iSU" : "" , "uSV" : "( 0,0,0 )" , "iPB" : 0 , "bHBC" : 6 , "cHRB" : 1 , "cHSM" : 1 , "hRBIP" : 1 , "cIH" : 0 , "cIP" : 0 , "bIP" : 0 , "aBP" : 1 , "iGO" : 0 , "sSC" : 0 , "sBC" : 0 , "dBC" : 0 , "cSC" : 0 , "iSC" : 0 , "pSId" : "1bdf72" , "toT" : 5.756089} , { "iBS" : 0 , "bSTOP" : 0 , "aSTOP" : 0 , "bSPB" : "STRIPE BALLS" , "aSPB" : "STRIPE BALLS" , "lBP" : [ 9] , "iBP" : [ ] , "bP" : [ 9] , "iTO" : 0 , "iCOPG" : 0 , "nTCCOP" : 0 , "iCOPS" : 0 , "cBP" : "( 0.0779118,0.04,-0.53505 )" , "iF" : "( -0.2458796,0,0.2141081 )" , "iP" : "( 0.1080778,0.04,-0.5613181 )" , "cA" : "( 0,311.0488,0 )" , "iTBA" : 1 , "tBID" : 9 , "tBP" : "( -0.4028816,0.04000001,-0.1177362 )" , "tT" : 25.78172 , "iSU" : "" , "uSV" : "( 0,0,0 )" , "iPB" : 0 , "bHBC" : 0 , "cHRB" : 1 , "cHSM" : 1 , "hRBIP" : 1 , "cIH" : 0 , "cIP" : 0 , "bIP" : 0 , "aBP" : 1 , "iGO" : 0 , "sSC" : 1 , "sBC" : 0 , "dBC" : 0 , "cSC" : 0 , "iSC" : 0 , "pSId" : "1bdf72" , "toT" : 25.76452} , { "iBS" : 0 , "bSTOP" : 0 , "aSTOP" : 0 , "bSPB" : "STRIPE BALLS" , "aSPB" : "STRIPE BALLS" , "lBP" : [ 15] , "iBP" : [ 0] , "bP" : [ 15 , 0] , "iTO" : 0 , "iCOPG" : 0 , "nTCCOP" : 0 , "iCOPS" : 0 , "cBP" : "( -0.6202361,0.04,0.07899453 )" , "iF" : "( 0.5099897,0,-0.003231468 )" , "iP" : "( -0.6602353,0.04,0.07924797 )" , "cA" : "( 0,90.36304,0 )" , "iTBA" : 1 , "tBID" : 15 , "tBP" : "( 0.4645979,0.04000001,0.1173781 )" , "tT" : 17.43617 , "iSU" : "" , "uSV" : "( 0,0,0 )" , "iPB" : 0 , "bHBC" : 5 , "cHRB" : 1 , "cHSM" : 1 , "hRBIP" : 1 , "cIH" : 1 , "cIP" : 1 , "bIP" : 0 , "aBP" : 1 , "iGO" : 0 , "sSC" : 0 , "sBC" : 0 , "dBC" : 0 , "cSC" : 0 , "iSC" : 0 , "pSId" : "1bdf72" , "toT" : 17.41947} , { "iBS" : 0 , "bSTOP" : 0 , "aSTOP" : 0 , "bSPB" : "SOLID BALLS" , "aSPB" : "SOLID BALLS" , "lBP" : [ 5] , "iBP" : [ ] , "bP" : [ 5] , "iTO" : 0 , "iCOPG" : 0 , "nTCCOP" : 0 , "iCOPS" : 0 , "cBP" : "( 0.4321823,0.03999999,-0.146901 )" , "iF" : "( 0.1381158,0,0.1290963 )" , "iP" : "( 0.40296,0.03999999,-0.174215 )" , "cA" : "( 0,46.93323,0 )" , "iTBA" : 1 , "tBID" : 5 , "tBP" : "( 0.5929074,0.04,0.002491749 )" , "tT" : 25.0796 , "iSU" : "" , "uSV" : "( 0,0,0 )" , "iPB" : 0 , "bHBC" : 0 , "cHRB" : 1 , "cHSM" : 1 , "hRBIP" : 1 , "cIH" : 0 , "cIP" : 0 , "bIP" : 0 , "aBP" : 1 , "iGO" : 0 , "sSC" : 1 , "sBC" : 0 , "dBC" : 0 , "cSC" : 0 , "iSC" : 0 , "pSId" : "2cfdd0" , "toT" : 26.25124} , { "iBS" : 0 , "bSTOP" : 0 , "aSTOP" : 0 , "bSPB" : "SOLID BALLS" , "aSPB" : "SOLID BALLS" , "lBP" : [ 7] , "iBP" : [ ] , "bP" : [ 7] , "iTO" : 0 , "iCOPG" : 0 , "nTCCOP" : 0 , "iCOPS" : 0 , "cBP" : "( 0.6570191,0.04,0.06490942 )" , "iF" : "( 0.1059603,0,-0.2250292 )" , "iP" : "( 0.6399788,0.04,0.1010982 )" , "cA" : "( 0,154.7855,0 )" , "iTBA" : 1 , "tBID" : 7 , "tBP" : "( 0.7849708,0.04000001,-0.1436278 )" , "tT" : 27.20016 , "iSU" : "" , "uSV" : "( 0,0,0 )" , "iPB" : 0 , "bHBC" : 1 , "cHRB" : 1 , "cHSM" : 1 , "hRBIP" : 1 , "cIH" : 0 , "cIP" : 0 , "bIP" : 0 , "aBP" : 1 , "iGO" : 0 , "sSC" : 1 , "sBC" : 0 , "dBC" : 0 , "cSC" : 0 , "iSC" : 0 , "pSId" : "2cfdd0" , "toT" : 27.18202} , { "iBS" : 0 , "bSTOP" : 0 , "aSTOP" : 0 , "bSPB" : "SOLID BALLS" , "aSPB" : "SOLID BALLS" , "lBP" : [ 2] , "iBP" : [ ] , "bP" : [ 2] , "iTO" : 0 , "iCOPG" : 0 , "nTCCOP" : 0 , "iCOPS" : 0 , "cBP" : "( 0.4290362,0.04,-0.4845348 )" , "iF" : "( -0.1070574,0,0.3149122 )" , "iP" : "( 0.4419109,0.04,-0.5224062 )" , "cA" : "( 0,341.2241,0 )" , "iTBA" : 1 , "tBID" : 2 , "tBP" : "( 0.35649,0.04000001,-0.2899367 )" , "tT" : 27.1818 , "iSU" : "" , "uSV" : "( 0,0,0 )" , "iPB" : 0 , "bHBC" : 2 , "cHRB" : 1 , "cHSM" : 1 , "hRBIP" : 1 , "cIH" : 0 , "cIP" : 0 , "bIP" : 0 , "aBP" : 1 , "iGO" : 0 , "sSC" : 0 , "sBC" : 0 , "dBC" : 0 , "cSC" : 0 , "iSC" : 0 , "pSId" : "2cfdd0" , "toT" : 27.15446} , { "iBS" : 0 , "bSTOP" : 0 , "aSTOP" : 0 , "bSPB" : "SOLID BALLS" , "aSPB" : "SOLID BALLS" , "lBP" : [ 4] , "iBP" : [ ] , "bP" : [ 4] , "iTO" : 0 , "iCOPG" : 0 , "nTCCOP" : 0 , "iCOPS" : 0 , "cBP" : "( 0.5885352,0.04,-0.1053962 )" , "iF" : "( -0.2677357,0,0.2490637 )" , "iP" : "( 0.6178222,0.04,-0.1326408 )" , "cA" : "( 0,312.9308,0 )" , "iTBA" : 1 , "tBID" : 4 , "tBP" : "( -0.2299831,0.04000001,0.5813306 )" , "tT" : 16.6083 , "iSU" : "" , "uSV" : "( 0,0,0 )" , "iPB" : 0 , "bHBC" : 2 , "cHRB" : 1 , "cHSM" : 1 , "hRBIP" : 1 , "cIH" : 0 , "cIP" : 0 , "bIP" : 0 , "aBP" : 1 , "iGO" : 0 , "sSC" : 1 , "sBC" : 0 , "dBC" : 0 , "cSC" : 0 , "iSC" : 0 , "pSId" : "2cfdd0" , "toT" : 16.57993} , { "iBS" : 0 , "bSTOP" : 0 , "aSTOP" : 0 , "bSPB" : "SOLID BALLS" , "aSPB" : "SOLID BALLS" , "lBP" : [ ] , "iBP" : [ ] , "bP" : [ ] , "iTO" : 0 , "iCOPG" : 0 , "nTCCOP" : 0 , "iCOPS" : 0 , "cBP" : "( -0.1893151,0.04,-0.4421305 )" , "iF" : "( 0.5092477,0,-0.02769054 )" , "iP" : "( -0.2292561,0.04,-0.4399587 )" , "cA" : "( 0,93.11242,0 )" , "iTBA" : 1 , "tBID" : 6 , "tBP" : "( 0.6927831,0.04,-0.5543976 )" , "tT" : 17.58389 , "iSU" : "" , "uSV" : "( 0,0,0 )" , "iPB" : 0 , "bHBC" : 5 , "cHRB" : 1 , "cHSM" : 1 , "hRBIP" : 0 , "cIH" : 0 , "cIP" : 0 , "bIP" : 0 , "aBP" : 0 , "iGO" : 0 , "sSC" : 0 , "sBC" : 0 , "dBC" : 0 , "cSC" : 0 , "iSC" : 0 , "pSId" : "2cfdd0" , "toT" : 25.99698} , { "iBS" : 0 , "bSTOP" : 0 , "aSTOP" : 0 , "bSPB" : "STRIPE BALLS" , "aSPB" : "STRIPE BALLS" , "lBP" : [ 13] , "iBP" : [ ] , "bP" : [ 13] , "iTO" : 0 , "iCOPG" : 0 , "nTCCOP" : 0 , "iCOPS" : 0 , "cBP" : "( 0.6336635,0.04,0.07858364 )" , "iF" : "( -0.1611403,0,0.06044259 )" , "iP" : "( 0.6711156,0.04,0.06453566 )" , "cA" : "( 0,290.5607,0 )" , "iTBA" : 1 , "tBID" : 13 , "tBP" : "( -0.5944556,0.04000001,0.5183017 )" , "tT" : 14.77339 , "iSU" : "" , "uSV" : "( 0,0,0 )" , "iPB" : 0 , "bHBC" : 2 , "cHRB" : 1 , "cHSM" : 1 , "hRBIP" : 1 , "cIH" : 0 , "cIP" : 0 , "bIP" : 0 , "aBP" : 1 , "iGO" : 0 , "sSC" : 1 , "sBC" : 0 , "dBC" : 0 , "cSC" : 0 , "iSC" : 0 , "pSId" : "1bdf72" , "toT" : 14.75704} , { "iBS" : 0 , "bSTOP" : 0 , "aSTOP" : 0 , "bSPB" : "STRIPE BALLS" , "aSPB" : "STRIPE BALLS" , "lBP" : [ 10] , "iBP" : [ ] , "bP" : [ 10] , "iTO" : 0 , "iCOPG" : 0 , "nTCCOP" : 0 , "iCOPS" : 0 , "cBP" : "( -0.6597628,0.04,0.539317 )" , "iF" : "( 0.3268366,0,-0.3805755 )" , "iP" : "( -0.6858233,0.04,0.5696625 )" , "cA" : "( 0,139.3442,0 )" , "iTBA" : 1 , "tBID" : 10 , "tBP" : "( 0.3564146,0.04000001,-0.5567175 )" , "tT" : 10.13039 , "iSU" : "" , "uSV" : "( 0,0,0 )" , "iPB" : 1 , "bHBC" : 4 , "cHRB" : 1 , "cHSM" : 1 , "hRBIP" : 1 , "cIH" : 0 , "cIP" : 0 , "bIP" : 0 , "aBP" : 1 , "iGO" : 0 , "sSC" : 0 , "sBC" : 0 , "dBC" : 0 , "cSC" : 0 , "iSC" : 0 , "pSId" : "1bdf72" , "toT" : 10.11172} , { "iBS" : 0 , "bSTOP" : 0 , "aSTOP" : 0 , "bSPB" : "STRIPE BALLS" , "aSPB" : "STRIPE BALLS" , "lBP" : [ ] , "iBP" : [ ] , "bP" : [ ] , "iTO" : 0 , "iCOPG" : 0 , "nTCCOP" : 0 , "iCOPS" : 0 , "cBP" : "( 0.2228186,0.04,0.1685899 )" , "iF" : "( -0.246861,0,-0.3906604 )" , "iP" : "( 0.2441863,0.04,0.2024045 )" , "cA" : "( 0,212.2891,0 )" , "iTBA" : 1 , "tBID" : 8 , "tBP" : "( -0.2992525,0.04000001,-0.5290359 )" , "tT" : 12.02916 , "iSU" : "" , "uSV" : "( 0,0,0 )" , "iPB" : 1 , "bHBC" : 3 , "cHRB" : 1 , "cHSM" : 1 , "hRBIP" : 0 , "cIH" : 0 , "cIP" : 0 , "bIP" : 0 , "aBP" : 0 , "iGO" : 0 , "sSC" : 0 , "sBC" : 0 , "dBC" : 0 , "cSC" : 0 , "iSC" : 0 , "pSId" : "1bdf72" , "toT" : 12.01164} , { "iBS" : 0 , "bSTOP" : 0 , "aSTOP" : 0 , "bSPB" : "SOLID BALLS" , "aSPB" : "SOLID BALLS" , "lBP" : [ 6] , "iBP" : [ ] , "bP" : [ 6] , "iTO" : 0 , "iCOPG" : 0 , "nTCCOP" : 0 , "iCOPS" : 0 , "cBP" : "( -0.3779429,0.03999999,0.07964184 )" , "iF" : "( 0.2466588,0,0.09699224 )" , "iP" : "( -0.4151683,0.03999999,0.0650039 )" , "cA" : "( 0,68.53404,0 )" , "iTBA" : 1 , "tBID" : 6 , "tBP" : "( 0.7465774,0.04000001,0.5018011 )" , "tT" : 21.34981 , "iSU" : "" , "uSV" : "( 0,0,0 )" , "iPB" : 1 , "bHBC" : 2 , "cHRB" : 1 , "cHSM" : 1 , "hRBIP" : 1 , "cIH" : 0 , "cIP" : 0 , "bIP" : 0 , "aBP" : 1 , "iGO" : 0 , "sSC" : 1 , "sBC" : 0 , "dBC" : 0 , "cSC" : 0 , "iSC" : 0 , "pSId" : "2cfdd0" , "toT" : 21.3332} , { "iBS" : 0 , "bSTOP" : 0 , "aSTOP" : 0 , "bSPB" : "SOLID BALLS" , "aSPB" : "SOLID BALLS" , "lBP" : [ 8] , "iBP" : [ ] , "bP" : [ 8] , "iTO" : 0 , "iCOPG" : 0 , "nTCCOP" : 0 , "iCOPS" : 0 , "cBP" : "( 0.9329018,0.04,0.4941435 )" , "iF" : "( -0.230935,0,-0.1550016 )" , "iP" : "( 0.9661143,0.04,0.5164354 )" , "cA" : "( 0,236.1308,0 )" , "iTBA" : 1 , "tBID" : 8 , "tBP" : "( -0.6080351,0.04000002,-0.4977565 )" , "tT" : 22.92525 , "iSU" : "" , "uSV" : "( 0,0,0 )" , "iPB" : 1 , "bHBC" : 2 , "cHRB" : 1 , "cHSM" : 1 , "hRBIP" : 0 , "cIH" : 0 , "cIP" : 0 , "bIP" : 1 , "aBP" : 1 , "iGO" : 1 , "sSC" : 0 , "sBC" : 0 , "dBC" : 0 , "cSC" : 0 , "iSC" : 0 , "pSId" : "2" , "toT" : 22.90602}] , "winner" : "2" , "reason" : 12}]
```

I have tried reading the json file and separately open that 'shots' column from json file but it fails.

```
#reading data
with open("z.txt", 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as datafile:
    data = json.load(datafile)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
shots = pd.DataFrame([d["shots"] for d in data])
```

I want to extract the "_id" along with all the columns that would be inside "shots" in a single dataframe.

Comment: What exactly is the input. What's `data`? Is that the first example? Please provide a minimal example

Comment: data is around 500,000 rows of  the example I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(data, "shots", "_id")
```

Output of the head "_id" is located in the last column, all the others columns are what's inside data:

```
   iBS  bSTOP  aSTOP          bSPB          aSPB   lBP iBP    bP  iTO  iCOPG  nTCCOP  iCOPS                             cBP                                          iF                              iP                                       cA  iTBA  tBID                                   tBP         tT iSU        uSV  iPB  bHBC  cHRB  cHSM  hRBIP  cIH  cIP  bIP  aBP  iGO  sSC  sBC  dBC  cSC  iSC    pSId        toT  _id
0    1      1      1   NOT DECIDED   NOT DECIDED   [1]  []   [1]    0      0       0      0  ( -0.6728522,0.04,-0.5520813 )          ( 0.480835,-2.9104E-16,0.1699932 )  ( -0.7105647,0.04,-0.5654141 )    ( 6.539359E-14,70.5296,2.670466E-14 )     1     2            ( 0.724014,0.0335,-0.041 )  12.663670                   0     7     1     1      1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0  2cfdd0  12.634380  abc
1    0      1      0   NOT DECIDED   SOLID BALLS   [3]  []   [3]    0      0       0      0     ( 1.07788,0.04,-0.5111128 )       ( -0.2340834,1.694598E-16,0.4531059 )    ( 1.096239,0.04,-0.5466505 )  ( -3.80758E-14,332.6783,-1.613636E-14 )     1     3      ( 0.4538818,0.04000001,0.54636 )  15.641220      ( 0,0,0 )    0     4     1     1      1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0  2cfdd0  15.621620  abc
2    0      0      0   SOLID BALLS   SOLID BALLS    []  []    []    0      0       0      0   ( 0.1115417,0.04,-0.1958274 )  ( 0.002243765,-1.426218E-18,0.0006675497 )  ( 0.07320246,0.04,-0.2072338 )    ( 6.981425E-14,73.43156,3.15853E-14 )     1     5  ( 0.7939866,0.04000001,-0.07077976 )  24.505560      ( 0,0,0 )    0     0     0     0      0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  2cfdd0  24.484300  abc
3    0      0      0  STRIPE BALLS  STRIPE BALLS  [14]  []  [14]    0      0       0      0   ( -0.1471594,0.04,0.2157262 )                  ( 0.09524104,0,0.1471072 )    ( -0.1688982,0.04,0.182149 )                         ( 0,32.92009,0 )     1    14  ( -0.06695016,0.04000001,0.3848823 )   9.197196      ( 0,0,0 )    0     0     1     1      1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0  1bdf72   9.181252  abc
4    0      0      0  STRIPE BALLS  STRIPE BALLS  [12]  []  [12]    0      0       0      0    ( 0.3852863,0.04,0.4167935 )                    ( 0.282476,0,0.2797301 )    ( 0.3568642,0.04,0.3886477 )                         ( 0,45.27985,0 )     1    12    ( 0.6180266,0.04000001,0.5658391 )   6.139053      ( 0,0,0 )    0     7     1     1      1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0  1bdf72   6.123772  abc
```

> Documentation:
>
> [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):
>   “Normalize” semi-structured JSON data into a flat table.